# Insertion Sort in Python with for loops

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I'm learning Python from a web source which implemented the Insertion Sort algorithm using a combination of for loop and while loop. I thought of practicing the code by myself and I coded an algorithm using only for loops. I need some feedback on whether my code is correct, and whether its valid.

```
def insertionSort(lst):
    for i in range(1,len(lst)):
        temp = lst[i]

        for j in range(0,i):
            if lst[j] > temp:

                lst[i], lst[j] = lst[j], lst[i]
        
    return lst

lst = [8, 6, 4, 20, 24, 2, 10, 12]
print(insertionSort(lst))
```

The output is: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20, 24]

Comment: This is not insertion sort.

Comment: To check if the code works correctly, start with a bunch of test. Especially facing the corner cases.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm could be called insertion sort in a broad sense, but it is different from what is commonly understood by insertion sort, as it compares the `temp` value with **all** previous values, while standard insertion sort only compares `temp` with the *greater* values among the previous values, and with one additional value that will become `temp`'s predecessor (if there is one).

This means your implementation will have a *best case* time complexity that is O(²), while the *best case* time complexity of the standard algorithm is O(). That best case occurs when the input is already sorted.

The *typical* insertion sort algorithm will have the inner loop going backwards, visiting values in descending order, and **stopping** when it finds a value that is less than (or equal to) the value to move (`temp`). During this loop the swaps are done with 2 **consecutive** values, and this can be improved by delaying the insertion of `temp` so that values only have to be copied one place to the right until the insertion point is found.

An implementation of that in Python could look like this:

```
def insertionSort(lst):
    for i, temp in enumerate(lst):
        for j in range(i - 1, -1, -1):
            if lst[j] <= temp: # Found insertion point?
                lst[j + 1] = temp
                break
            lst[j + 1] = lst[j] # Make room for temp
        else: # temp is the least value so far: insert at the start
            lst[0] = temp
        
    return lst
```

#### Correctness testing

To test yourself whether your implementation correctly sorts a list, you can bombard your function with random input. For instance like this:

```
import random

for size in range(100):
    lst = list(range(size))
    random.shuffle(lst)
    finallist = lst[:]
    insertionSort(finallist)
    if finallist != sorted(finallist):
        print("Not sorted correctly:", lst, "to", finallist)
        break
else:
    print("All tests passed successfully")
```

Comment: Thanks @trincot, I learnt a lot by understanding your code and analyzing it with mine. So a standard while loop insertion sort is much better time complexity wise, and it also gives meaning to the problem statement.

Comment: Yes, but realise that the difference in time complexity only applies to the **best case** time complexity. Your version has the same **average case** and **worst case** time complexity as the more standard version.